# database import error

Tags: php, database, importexport

i have imported my local magento database to live one with phpmyadmin. but when im trying to access my web site i get this error log.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:63:"Item (Mage_Core_Model_Store) with the same id "0" already exist";i:1;s:891:"#0 /public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(576): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Store))
#1 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Store/Collection.php(174): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load(false, false)
#2 /public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(752): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Store_Collection->load()
#3 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(624): Varien_Data_Collection->count()
#4 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#5 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#6 /public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `core_store`, `core_website` and `core_store_group` tables.

There is a possibility that in these tables Admin is created as `1` for id.
It should be `0` in all cases.

If you correct them, the error will probably be gone.

Answer (score 1):

In another case, you might have `0` for `id` but there can be ***multiple rows inserted with the same value***.

Delete such duplicate rows from `core_store`, `core_website` and `core_store_group` tables and the issue will be solved.